# Excel: create multiple rows for each row in another table (formula preferred)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I can't seem to figure out this simple solution for an Excel workbook (preferably solved without VBA). **For each row in a 'base table', four other rows should be created in an 'extended table'**. I would like to learn thus doing this by the means of formulae would be perfect.

**Example:**

Base table:

```
JOB-ORDER
1
2
```

Extended table:

```
JOB-ORDER, Description, Qty, Price, Amount
1, hours worked, SUM VLOOKUP(1), SUM VLOOKUP(1), Qty*Price
1, driven miles, SUM VLOOKUP(1), SUM VLOOKUP(1), Qty*Price
1, some text, SUM VLOOKUP(1), SUM VLOOKUP(1), Qty*Price
1, some text, SUM VLOOKUP(1), SUM VLOOKUP(1), Qty*Price
2, hours worked, SUM VLOOKUP(2), SUM VLOOKUP(2), Qty*Price
2, driven miles, SUM VLOOKUP(2), SUM VLOOKUP(2), Qty*Price
2, some text, SUM VLOOKUP(2), SUM VLOOKUP(2), Qty*Price
2, some text, SUM VLOOKUP(2), SUM VLOOKUP(2), Qty*Price
```

**Functional:**

What basically happens is that for each row in 'base table':

- multiple rows are created in 'extended table'
- JOB-ORDER is copied from base to extended
- Description is filled in according to the row-number we're in (first row = 'worked hours', second row = 'driven miles', third row = '...', fourth row = '...')
- Qty, Price = SUM VLOOKUP based on JOB-ORDER in third table

I have created all aspects of this particular workbook (there is more than this), except for the duplication of 1 row to multiple rows which is crucial for the SUM VLOOKUP and thus the overall solution.

**Bonus points:**
'Extended table' layout should have switching layout aka

- First four rows (aka JOB-ORDER 1) should have background white
- Second four rows (aka JOB-ORDER 2) should have background red
- Third four rows (aka JOB-ORDER 3) should have background white
- ...

Does anyone have some guidance, advice, or a particular solution that I can implement?

Comment: Your data setup and desired results are not clear to me.  But for formulas in your extended table, you could `INDEX` into your base table. And you would use some combination of `ROW`, `MOD`, `INT` and `CHOOSE` to figure out which row you are reading from the base table, and what you are going to write out in the extended table.  For the coloring, you can use conditional formatting.

Comment: Hi Ron, about the desired result. The essence lies in the fact that for each 'JOB-ORDER'-row in 'base table', four other rows in the 'extended' should be created with the given JOB-ORDER. I tried to solve it earlier with the described functions, but I could not figure it out.

Comment: Show the formulas you have tried, along with data samples and the results.

Comment: The best suggestion I have for you to get started on your project is checking out some of the many tutorials for Excel.  YouTube has good place for beginners to find tutorials.  Please check out the [tour] as well as [ask] and [mcve]

Answer (score 2):

Here are formulas for your first two columns.  Examine them closely to see how the indexing into `baseTable` repeats the appropriate row four times; and also how the CHOOSE number cycles repeatedly `1...4`.  You can use one of these methods to figure out your other columns, which you do not show in `baseTable`.

**JOB-ORDER Formula**

```
=INDEX(baseTable,CEILING(ROWS($1:1)/4,1),1)
```

**Description Formula**

```
=CHOOSE(MOD(ROWS($1:1)-1,4)+1,"hours worked","driven miles","some text","some text")
```

[image]